# NSMutableArray showing (null)/nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

Hi i have a function like this

```
- (void)save{
        NSLog(@" %@ %@ %@ %@",AppAddressLine,AppCustomerName,AppPhoneNumber,AppPriceTier);

        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewInAppCustomer.plist"];
        NSMutableArray *MainRoot=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSMutableDictionary *ContentDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [ContentDictionary setValue:AppCustomerName  forKey:@"CustomerName"];
        [ContentDictionary setValue:AppAddressLine forKey:@"CustomerAddress"];
        [ContentDictionary setValue:AppPhoneNumber forKey:@"CustomerPhoneNumber"];
        [ContentDictionary setValue:AppPriceTier forKey:@"CustomerPriceTier"];
        [MainRoot addObject:ContentDictionary];
        [MainRoot writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",MainRoot);

}
```

when I print with

```
NSLog(@" %@ %@ %@ %@",AppAddressLine,AppCustomerName,AppPhoneNumber,AppPriceTier);
```

it is showing a correct value,

but this line

```
NSLog(@"%@",MainRoot);
```

displays `nil` as its value.

Can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: Check that file exist or not

Comment: Also, is your plist a array or a dict?

Comment: i just created that plist through programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
NSMutableArray *MainRoot=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

will return `nil` if:

> the file can’t be opened or the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array

so you have a non-existent or an invalid file.

So, you should ensure that the file is created before this code runs, or, better, check the result and create a new empty array if you need to.

```
if (MainRoot == nil) MainRoot = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: So do u have any solutions?

Comment: Updated. Incidentally, you should improve your variable names to follow coding standards.

Comment: can u pls tell me one example so i can improve those parts

Comment: @Akhilrajtr has provided a good example for naming. Variables have lower case first letters and are camel cased. Class names start with a capital first letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, create the file if it not exist and then write to it

```
- (void)save{
        NSLog(@" %@ %@ %@ %@",AppAddressLine,AppCustomerName,AppPhoneNumber,AppPriceTier);

        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewInAppCustomer.plist"];
        NSMutableArray *mainRoot;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {

             [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
             mainRoot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        } else {
             mainRoot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        }
        ....
}
```

Comment: same issue stillthere